# How would you translate the concept of an X-sitter

Tags: single-word-requests

house-sitter, babysitter, dog-sitter, etc.

Would it be an x-spektisto? domospektisto, bebospektisto, hundospektisto?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think something involving the root “vart-” would be suitable. PIV has the following definition:

> Gardi k prizorgi estulon, kiu bezonas helpon pro sia juneco, nefortikeco: *varti bebon, hundeton;*

It has a definition of *vartisto* as someone who professionally *vartas*, so I don’t see any reason why you couldn’t say *infanvartisto* or *hundvartisto* to be more specific. Here is an example from *Vespera ruĝo anoncas ventegon* (via the [Tekstaro](http://tekstaro.com)):

> Kaj la juna virino — ŝi kredeble estis **infanvartistino** — ridetis afable kaj entute ŝi impresis miranta.

Answer (score 7):

If you want a general word, you should use **-zorganto** or **-zorgisto**. You should prefer -isto for someone who does it regularly or professionally.

If you want to be more specific, there are different verbs from which you can add the ending -anto or -isto:

- [varti](http://vortaro.net/#varti) for a child, or a weak being like a puppy
- [flegi](http://vortaro.net/#flegi) for sick people
- [mastrumi](http://vortaro.net/#mastrumi) for a house, a construction